# Faster data reformatting with groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

So I have a DataFrame that looks something along these lines:

```py
import pandas as pd

ddd = {
    'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    'b': [22, 25, 18, 53, 19, 8, 75, 11, 49, 64],
    'c': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(ddd)
```

What I need is to group the data by the `'c'` column and apply some data transformations. At the moment I'm doing this:

```py
def do_stuff(d: pd.DataFrame):
    if d.shape[0] >= 2:
        return pd.DataFrame(
            {
                'start': [d.a.values[0]],
                'end': [d.a.values[d.shape[0] - 1]],
                'foo': [d.a.sum()],
                'bar': [d.b.mean()]
            }
        )
    else:
        return pd.DataFrame()

r = df.groupby('c').apply(lambda x: do_stuff(x))
```

Which gives the correct result:

```
     start  end   foo        bar
c                               
1 0    1.0  3.0   6.0  21.666667
2 0    4.0  5.0   9.0  36.000000
4 0    7.0  9.0  24.0  45.000000
```

The problem is that this approach appears to be too slow. On my actual data it runs in around 0.7 seconds which is too long and needs to be ideally much faster.

Is there any way I can do this faster? Or maybe there's some other faster method not involving `groupby` that I could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could first filter `df` for the "c" values that appear 2 or more times; then use `groupby` + named aggregation:

```
msk = df['c'].value_counts() >= 2
out = (df[df['c'].isin(msk.index[msk])]
       .groupby('c')
       .agg(start=('a','first'), end=('a','last'), foo=('a','sum'), bar=('b','mean')))
```

You could also do:

```
out = (df[df.groupby('c')['c'].transform('count').ge(2)]
       .groupby('c')
       .agg(start=('a','first'), 
            end=('a','last'), 
            foo=('a','sum'), 
            bar=('b','mean')))
```

or

```
msk = df['c'].value_counts() >= 2
out = (df[df['c'].isin(msk.index[msk])]
       .groupby('c')
       .agg({'a':['first','last','sum'], 'b':'mean'})
       .set_axis(['start','end','foo','bar'], axis=1))
```

Output:

```
   start  end  foo        bar
c                            
1      1    3    6  21.666667
2      4    5    9  36.000000
4      7    9   24  45.000000
```

---

*Some benchmarks:*

```
>>> %timeit out = df.groupby('c').apply(lambda x: do_stuff(x))
6.49 ms ± 335 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
>>> %timeit msk = df['c'].value_counts() >= 2; out = (df[df['c'].isin(msk.index[msk])].groupby('c').agg(start=('a','first'), end=('a','last'), foo=('a','sum'), bar=('b','mean')))
7.6 ms ± 211 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
>>> %timeit out = (df[df.groupby('c')['c'].transform('count').ge(2)].groupby('c').agg(start=('a','first'), end=('a','last'), foo=('a','sum'), bar=('b','mean')))
7.86 ms ± 509 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
>>> %timeit msk = df['c'].value_counts() >= 2; out = (df[df['c'].isin(msk.index[msk])].groupby('c').agg({'a':['first','last','sum'], 'b':'mean'}).set_axis(['start','end','foo','bar'], axis=1))
4.68 ms ± 57.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```